# ¿Usar Puppeteer para seguir las redirecciones?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, puppeteer

Desde hace tiempo necesito una herramienta o funcionalidad que dada una URL inicial me devuelva la última URL del conjunto de redirecciones.

En primera instancia lo había intentado con PHP, pero no funcionaba con las redirecciones JavaScript, así que me recomendaron usar un browser headless.

Me leí la documentación de PhantomJS, lo instalé y lo probé. Resulta que, según comentario de muchos y de pruebas mías, no funcionaba muy bien con las redirecciones así que ahora estoy probando Google Chrome sin cabeza, haciendo uso de Puppeteer.

Mi código actual es el siguiente:

```
const argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));
var url = argv.url;
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--no-sandbox']});
     const page = await browser.newPage();
     await page.goto(url);
     await page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'load'});
     console.log(page.url());
     browser.close();
})();
```

Necesito ayuda con lo siguiente:

- Parece que mi script espera indefinidamente la carga de la página, me gustaría limitarlo a cierto tiempo.
- ¿Saben si existe una función que determine si la URL que se le está enviando es correcta? (Para evitar que salga un error al enviarle una URL incorrecta).
- ¿Qué otras mejoras le harían?

Answer (score 1):

> Parece que mi script espera indefinidamente la carga de la página, me gustaría limitarlo a cierto tiempo.

La función [waitForNavigation](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.18.0&show=api-pagewaitfornavigationoptions) acepta una opción `timeout` que le puedes indicar el máximo tiempo a esperar, en milisegundos. Para esperar 10 segundos, por ejemplo:

`await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'load', timeout: '10000' });`

Por defecto está puesto a 30000 (30 segundos) así que no debería esperar indefinidamente, ¿estás seguro de que está esperando idefinidamente?

Luego, creo que el problema está en que estás poniendo el `waitForNavigation` después del `goto`, y como el `goto` tiene un `await` estás haciendo que espere a que termine el `goto` y luego le dices que espere a que la navegación termine, pero ya habrá terminado, así que se queda ahí esperando a navegar.

Prueba algo así:

```
const argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));
var url = argv.url;
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--no-sandbox']});
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await Promise.all([
        page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 10000 }),
        page.goto(url)
    ]);

    console.log(page.url());
    browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Gracias por tomarte la molestia de responderme, lo que dices tiene sentido, no obstante, he probado tu código y no me devuelve la última URL, me devuelve 2 intermedias ¿por qué ocurre esto?. Lo que he hecho es reemplazar tu archivo por el mio y no devuelven lo mismo.